# How to find all roots and maxima and minima and graph them

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I need to find all the roots of this function. 
I know it is simple to find by hand, however, I wish to learn how to do it so I can apply it later. The problem is that it only gives me one root.

```
Distance[t_] := t*(t - 1)*(t - 1.5)^2*(t - 3)
Velocity[t_] := Simplify[Distance'[t]]
FindRoot[Velocity[t], {t, -100, 100}]

{t -> 2.63641}
```

I can find the minimum and maximum. However, how would I plot them on the same graph as the function without copy and pasting the points manually into a list?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `Solve[Velocity[t] == 0, t]`?

Comment: Gah! You might as well close the question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Andy said, you can simply use

```
solutions = Solve[velocity[t] == 0, t]
```

to find the extrema: `{{t -> 0.291169}, {t -> 1.17242}, {t -> 1.5}, {t -> 2.63641}}`

To answer the second part of your question:

> However, how would I plot them on the same graph as the function without copy and pasting the points manually into a list?

You can use `Show` to draw multiple plots or graphics in the same coordinate system:

```
Show[
 Plot[distance[t], {t, 0, 3}],
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{t, distance[t]} /. solutions]}]]
```

Result:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could also use `Epilog` to plot the points.

Comment: Thank you so much. When I find the maximum and minimum, I'll just define it as a variable.